# TensorFlow Object Detection API - Incorrect Dimensionality of Tensor in Source Code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I was going through the source code of TensorFlow's Object Detection API and came across this line in a member function of the SSD Meta-architecture a class - [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L229).

If I am not wrong, then shouldn't the box-encoding be a 3-D float tensor?

I am not an expert on TensorFlow in any way and my understanding is based on this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/resources/dims_types).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is a typo in the documentation.

Comment: I have fixed it and opened a pull request :) https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/2363

Comment: There's a legitimate reason for all those typos, I swear ;)